# if transformer secondary remains open, and primary is excited by sinusoidal source will there be heating produced?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics

If secondary coil of a transformer is left opened, and primary is excited by sinusoidal current source, will there be heating produced in the core of secondary ?

Comment: Do you mean "in the core" or "in the secondary"?

Comment: It's unclear because the primary and secondary share the *same* core (this is what makes it a transformer, and not two inductors).

Answer (score 2):

> If secondary coil of a transformer is left opened, and primary is
>   excited by sinusoidal current source, will there be heating produced
>   in the core of secondary ?

As both the secondary winding and primary winding **must** share the magnetic core of the transformer (or it isn't a transformer), this question boils down to examining what heat is produced in the core when there is no-load on the secondary.

The answer of course has to be **"yes"** unless the transformer is a perfect device with no losses. The losses in the situation described are called "iron" losses and this is a general heading for: -

1. Hysteresis losses (energy lost in reversing magnetic domains)
2. Eddy current losses in the core or core laminates (energy lost due to circulating currents in the non-zero resistances of the laminates.

These energy losses produce heat. Lower down the order of things but certainly not insignificant in other transformer applications the following should also be noted: -

- If the transformer is a high frequency device then dielectric losses
  should also be included.
- If the transformer has low magnetization inductance (primary
  inductance), the current that flows will be significant enough to
  generate \$I^2R\$ losses in the primary winding. Not to be confused with
  \$I^2R\$ losses due to load on the secondary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no it will not generate any heat in the secondary coil. Since the heat is produced when we connect any load on the secondary side which draws current and as the load current increases it will produce more heat in the secondary coil. But as long as you keep it open no heat is generated.

- The best example I can give is that when the mobile charger is not connected with mobile it doesn't heat but when you connect it to mobile to charge it. It starts heating.

Comment: The question asked about "the **core** of [the] secondary" suggesting they might not be asking about the windings of the secondary.